# CPU Cooler/Fans Don't Work In Ubuntu

Tags: fan, overheating, fancontrol

So this issue is an odd one and first for me. I have a new desktop build with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800X with ASRock X570 Taichi motherboard using a Kraken Z73 water cooler. I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. When booted into Ubuntu my fan speeds never change regardless of what I'm doing an CPU load. In addition the LCD display on the Z73 water cooler never changes temperature display. I even ran Prime95 for a couple minutes with my CPU at 100% load and the fans never increased in speeds. This worries me that I'm going to damage my hardware from overheating . When booted into Windows and running Prime95 after a minute or 2 the fans kick way up in speed as the processor passes the 60C mark.

Has anyone else encountered or seen anything similar with newer hardware or the Kraken z73 cooler. At this point I am avoiding booting into Ubuntu since I have no idea if my processor is running at high temperatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your coolant reservoir size, and if your fans are driven from coolant temperature, and how your coolant pump is driven, and what your power limit throttling is set to. But I would suggest, and with all due care, a much longer prime95 - torture test - test number 2 (hottest).

Here is an example with my i5-9600K and relatively small water cooled system. My coolant pump is always on at maximum, regardless. I always use turbostat, and I think it now works with many AMD processors:

```
doug@s18:~/temp-k-git/linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 15
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt RAMWatt
0.00    4487    355     32      1.56    1.89  <<< system idle, before test
76.01   4132    17570   65      86.28   1.91  <<< test started, CPU temperaure ramps up at an extremely fast rate, a few hundred degrees per second. This is normal, as a differential is required in order for heat to actually flow.
99.58   4099    22644   62      104.96  1.91 <<< the power level 2 throttle has enaged, otherwsie CPU freq would be 4.6 GHz.
100.15  4078    22627   63      99.92   1.91 <<< the power level 1 throttle has engaged already, as I have a short time constant set for it.
100.13  4074    22785   63      99.92   1.91 <<< power level 1 limit is 100 watts.
100.12  4070    22601   64      99.93   1.89 <<< notice the CPU temp is steady,
100.11  4067    22599   65      99.93   1.89 <<< the coolant hasn't even begun to heat up yet.
100.11  4063    22599   65      99.92   1.89
100.10  4061    22702   66      99.92   1.89
100.10  4057    22600   66      99.92   1.89
100.10  4054    22599   66      99.92   1.89
100.10  4052    22733   67      99.92   1.89
100.09  4050    22611   67      99.92   1.89
100.09  4047    22600   66      99.92   1.89 <<< 3 minutes into it.
100.10  4045    22707   67      99.92   1.89
100.10  4042    22610   67      99.92   1.89
100.10  4040    22602   67      99.93   1.89
100.10  4040    22594   67      99.92   1.89
100.10  4040    22692   67      99.92   1.89
100.10  4039    22596   68      99.92   1.89
100.10  4038    22603   67      99.92   1.89
100.11  4036    22615   68      99.92   1.89
100.12  4030    22724   67      99.92   1.92
100.13  4028    22606   68      99.92   1.93
100.13  4028    22616   68      99.92   1.93
100.13  4027    22693   67      99.92   1.93
100.13  4027    22604   67      99.93   1.94
100.13  4027    22598   67      99.92   1.94 <<< coolant is starting to warm up.
100.13  4027    22681   67      99.92   1.94 <<< you will have to take my word for it,
100.14  4025    22616   68      99.92   1.90 <<< I do not have a coolant temp indicator.
100.14  4025    22607   67      99.92   1.90
100.14  4024    22603   67      99.92   1.90
100.11  4042    22755   68      99.92   1.91
100.09  4049    22604   69      99.91   1.91
100.09  4049    22612   68      99.92   1.91
100.09  4050    22709   68      99.91   1.91
100.09  4051    22603   68      99.92   1.93
100.09  4052    23389   68      99.92   1.93
100.09  4050    22614   68      99.91   1.93
100.09  4051    22796   68      99.92   1.93
100.09  4051    22612   68      99.92   1.93
100.09  4052    22608   68      99.92   1.93
100.10  4046    22750   67      99.92   1.95
100.15  4022    22616   68      99.93   2.03
100.15  4022    22624   68      99.92   2.03
100.15  4021    22723   67      99.92   2.06
```

Actually, don't take my word for it about coolant temperature. If I stop the test, we'll see what the processor package temp reads, compared to before the test:

```
doug@s18:~/temp-k-git/linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 15
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt RAMWatt
100.10  4040    22710   67      99.97   1.90
100.10  4038    22605   68      99.92   1.90
37.10   4038    8672    40      38.10   1.89
0.00    4601    236     39      1.72    1.89  <<< coolant went up 8 maybe 7 degrees
0.01    4510    318     38      1.79    1.89
0.00    4601    213     38      1.87    1.89
```

Looking just by eye at your cooler verses mine, you have at least 2 times the coolant, and probably 3 times.

Comment: I installed GKraken so I could see the liquid temperature and speeds of the fans. I ran the test for a longer duration where the liquid temperature went from 25C to 32C when I stopped it (as in Windows even under full load for hours temp has never gone over 30C). The fans and pump never increased in speed so it appears under Windows it reacts to the CPU temp, and under Ubuntu the liquid temp. Sadly I have no way of knowing the CPU temp in Ubuntu as it doesn't appear under sensors command even after running sensors-detect.

Comment: Did you try turbostat? I am not very familiar with AMD processors, but I do know it now works with a lot of recent ones.

Comment: Yea on my machine I don't get PkgWatt or PkgTemp or RAMWatt

Comment: After rebooting I'm seeing more sensors show up now, and it appears SMBUSMATER is my CPU temperature and CPUTIN the the temperate of the CPU die being reported by the motherboard. If that is correct the CPU temperature appears to be holding pretty steady at 78C which is a little higher than I like but supposedly new 5000 series AMD Ryzens can safely go to 90C. And this is under 100% load with Prime95 that certainly isn't typical work loads for me.

Comment: O.K. great. Knowing the package temperature is fundamental, obviously, to this type of limit checking work. Yes, I typically set my temperature limit to about 74 degrees. As far as I know prime95 - torture test - test 2 is the most brutal stress program available. I have written many many stress programs myself, not even getting close. By the way, and taking things to the extreme, try prime95 one thread at a time, forced CPU affinity, to find if certain CPUs heat more than others. I.E. I can get higher temp by using fewer CPUs, for a more focused heat source.